# JNA/MS Word GoTo a bookmark in a Word document

Tags: jna

I'm using the `MSOfficeDemo/MSWord` classes.

I've added a new method to `MSWord` `gotoBookmark(String bm)`.

I've checked the API doco for `ComLateBindingObject`, the 4 calls below are the most likely candidates.
Below are the calls to `invokeNoReply()` that I've tried in my `gotoBookmark()` method.  But, they are returning the errors I've described.
The Bookmark does exist in the document.

```
    LONG lTypeBookmark = new LONG(-1);
    LONG lCount        = new LONG(1);
    LONG lInstanceOne  = new LONG(1);

    VARIANT[] args = new VARIANT[4];
    args[0] = new VARIANT(lTypeBookmark);
    args[1] = new VARIANT(lInstanceOne);
    args[2] = new VARIANT(lCount);
    args[3] = new VARIANT("TestBookmark");

    // This is from another method (insertText()) in the MSWord class that seems to work well.
    Selection pSelection = new Selection(this.getAutomationProperty("Selection", this.getIDispatch()));

    // 1.
    // Error returned: You entered multiple destinations for a page, line,     footnote, endnote, or comment.
    this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", this.getActiveDocument().getIDispatch(), args);

    // 2.
    // Error returned: You entered multiple destinations for a page, line, footnote, endnote, or comment.
    this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", pSelection.getIDispatch(), args);


    // 3.        
    // Error returned : Bad parameter.
    this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", pSelection, vtTypeBookmark, vtBookmarkName);

    // 4.  
    // Error retuned: Bad parameter.
    this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", pSelection, vtBookmarkName);
```

Comment: When using code that implements an API, it's best to try to keep exactly the same variable names as the source, e.g. `wdGoToBookmark` rather than `lTypeBookmark`, etc.  So those of us cross-checking to try to help you can easily check that things match. :)
`

Comment: Have you tried `this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", args);`?  Or `this.invokeNoReply("GoTo", new VARIANT(lTypeBookmark), new VARIANT(lInstanceOne), new VARIANT(lCount), new VARIANT("TestBookmark"))`?    I assume you have a named bookmark named "TestBookmark"?

Comment: I have now tried the two suggested calls to `invokeNoReply`, both return `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Unknown name. (puArgErr=)`. Yes, I have a named bookmark "TestBookmark" in my test Word document.  I can open my test document (in Word) and `GoTo` the bookmark.

Comment: OK, digging deeper...  `GoTo` has a return type (a range object) so you should be using the `invoke()` methods rather than the `invokeNoReply()`.  (sorry I missed this the first time and sorry for guessing at all this since I don't have Word on my VM. Perhaps I should install it to be more helpful... anyway....)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've (re)tried all 6 permutations of `invoke()`, plus your earlier suggestions (but with `invoke()`).  All produce the same error: `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Unknown name. (puArgErr=)`.  Running out of things to try.

Comment: This might be an issue: We are running MS Word 14.0.7162.5000 (32-bit) on Windows Edition: Windows 8.1 Pro, System Type: 64-bit.

Comment: Running out of hints.  Googling the error from steps 1 and 2 returns results (in a VBA context) indicating that having more than one document open/active at a time could be the cause of that, but I can't see how that would apply.    Since the args are optional, can you try searching for fewer args at a time?  e.g., 1st bookmark, or only by name without regard to number or direction, etc?

Comment: Well, I set Word up to start with only one active document (my test document).  I reran all my tests. All failed with the same errors.  We'll have to terminate this thread here. Looks like I'll have to go back to plan A.  Build my own DLL:  `java <-> using JNI <-> DLL <-> using COM <-> Word`.  Thanks anyway gentlemen.